# Sub or function not defined: Running a macro on excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Im trying to run a macro on excel to remove duplicate values from each column without affecting values from other columns and im getting the following error

`Compile Time error: Sub or function not defined`

Below is my macro

```
Sub RemoveDups()

Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim lLastCol As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Work through each sheet in the workbook.
For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Find the last column on the sheet.
    lLastCol = LastCell(wrkSht).Column

    'Work through each column on the sheet.
    For i = 1 To lLastCol

        'Find the last row for each column.
        lLastRow = LastCell(wrkSht, i).Row

        'Remove the duplicates.
        With wrkSht
            .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lLastRow, i)).RemoveDuplicates 
Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    Next i

Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

can someone help me out with this... thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
LastCell(wrkSht).
```

It can't find the LastCell function in your VBA project.

Comment: could rather be a comment than an answer?

Comment: Well it could, but it is the answer :) I was just checking before updating actually.

Comment: sorry guys..im new to vba...how do i do that?

Comment: My mistake, I thought that, as you've already added a sub, you knew how to. The problem is that we don't know what should be in that function so while I can say physically how to add one, it won't help.